# Firestore: conditionally update map based on map values

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for some technical advice on how to structure certain Firestore updates.

How do I update a document which is made up of key/value pairs, based on the `name` field of one of those key/value pairs:

```js
const farmRef = firestore.collection('farms').doc(uid)
// Something like: farmRef.mapUpdate(f => f.name === 'farm name' ? {...f, archived: true} : f)
```

At the moment, I can only achieve this through a bit of client side code, which I would like to avoid where possible.

It seems unnecessary to create a sub-collection if I only plan on having 0 - 10 key/value pairs per farm document. However, if I did the query would look like this:

```js
const userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(uid)
const farmRef = userRef.collection('farms').where("name", "==", "Clive Fields")
farmRef.update({archived: true})
```

Is Firestore geared towards making updates to simple documents, rather than documents containing `maps`?

*Current Setup*
[image]
*Potential Setup*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use field dot notation to locate a property of a nested map to update.

```
firestore
    .collection('farms')
    .doc(uid)
    .update({ "xxx.archived": true })
```

I would also seriously consider using a subcollection, as documents are not unlimited in size (1MB), so they can't grow indefinitely.  And you can't query and filter individual items in a nested map at all.  So if you think either of those things might be a problem, consider changing.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Also thank you for the the github repo you made a couple years ago on how to sync firebase and google sheets! I found it immensely useful for a client project I did last year